# Knitting a large plot_ly file in HTML

Tags: html, r, plotly, r-markdown, knitr

I am working with a large reddit text dataset utilizing about 5 million comments to create frequency tables and sentiment analysis. The number of subreddits that I selected was 33, which is cluttery to render in a single facet wrapped ggplot, so I opted for an interactive table with a drop-down menu to modify the values per subreddit selected. However, when I try to knit the file into HTML, the process takes about an hour and a half (which I expected, since the plotly file is 154 MB), and then fails with this error.

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS FinalProjectHTML.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output FinalProjectHTML.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-in-header "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpshXgZe\rmarkdown-str63c86fd53d4b.html" 

pandoc.exe: getMBlocks: VirtualAlloc MEM_COMMIT failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 251
Execution halted
```

Looking around for solutions, it seems that my problem is a matter of overloading my RAM and running out of memory in the process. So, I was wondering if there was a way I could solve this without turning my laptop into a jet engine.

To provide some context, the plotly table code is:

```
FrequencySubreddit <- tidysub_filter %>%
  count(subreddit, word, label, sort = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(desc(subreddit)) %>%
  group_by(subreddit) %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  plot_ly(
  x = ~n,
  y = ~word,
  type = "bar",
  transforms = list(list(
    type = 'filter',
    target = ~subreddit,
    operation = '=',
    value = unique(tidysub_filter$subreddit[1])
  ))
) %>%
  layout(title = "Word Frequency by Subreddit",
    yaxis = list(title = "Term", categoryorder = "trace", categoryarray = tidysub_filter$subreddit),
         xaxis = list(title = "Frequency"),
    font = list(family = "Times New Roman"),
    updatemenus = list(
    list(
      type = 'dropdown',
      active = 0,
      xanchor = "center",
      yanchor = "top",
      x = 1.2,
      y = 0.5,
      buttons = apply(as.data.frame(unique(tidysub_filter$subreddit)), 1,
                      function(x) list(method = 'restyle',args = list('transforms[0].value',x),label = x)))))
```

With tidysub_filter being a data.frame in the form of:

| Subreddit | Word | Label | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Addiction | Word 1 | MentalHealth | 1000 |
| Addiction | Word 2 | MentalHealth | 900 |
| Addiction | Word 3 | MentalHealth | 800 |
| Addiction | Word 4 | MentalHealth | 700 |
| Addiction | Word 5 | MentalHealth | 600 |
| Addiction | Word 6 | MentalHealth | 500 |
| Addiction | Word 7 | MentalHealth | 400 |
| Addiction | Word 8 | MentalHealth | 300 |
| Addiction | Word 9 | MentalHealth | 200 |
| Addiction | Word 10 | MentalHealth | 100 |
| neoliberal | Word 1 | Political | 1000 |
| neoliberal | Word 2 | Political | 900 |
| neoliberal | Word 3 | Political | 800 |
| neoliberal | Word 4 | Political | 700 |
| neoliberal | Word 5 | Political | 600 |
| neoliberal | Word 6 | Political | 500 |
| neoliberal | Word 7 | Political | 400 |
| neoliberal | Word 8 | Political | 300 |
| neoliberal | Word 9 | Political | 200 |
| neoliberal | Word 10 | Political | 100 |

And so on.

Furthermore, I limited the amount of stress the knitting process would take by saving the object into a .RData file and loading it into the environment before I knitted everything.

```
---
title: "title"
subtitle:
author: "me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tinytex)
setwd("E:/Rdata")
load("env.RData")

FrequencyIDF
```

**Note:** this is not the only interactive plot I want to insert; there are two other, of which one is a copy of the first one I just mentioned (with different data), while the other is a simple conversion of an existing ggplot. This last one I still haven't attempted to knit, so I don't know if I will incur in the same error. For reference, the code for it below, but I treated it in the same way as the FrequencySubreddit plot by loading it as an object.

```
tidysub_nrc_percentage <- tidysub_nrc %>%
  count(sentiment, label, day, year, sort = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sentiment, values_from = n) %>%
  mutate(total = select(., anger:trust) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(across(anger:trust , ~./total * 100)) %>%
  pivot_longer(anger:trust, names_to = "sentiment") %>%
  filter(sentiment != "negative", sentiment != "positive") %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(day), value, color = sentiment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(year ~ label) +
  labs(title = "Share of Emotion by Day", subtitle = "Percentage of total emotion categories by label and year") +
  ylab("Percentage (%)") + 
  xlab("Day") +
  placeholder_theme +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")

tidysub_nrc_percentage
plotlynrc <- ggplotly(tidysub_nrc_percentage)
```

**EDIT**

I finished loading my data again and I can provide you with the actual structure of the tidysub_filter object after it passes through the initial processing before the plot_ly command. The actual tidysub_filter file is too big to dput.

Just inputting this as:

```
Top10 <- tidysub_filter %>%
  count(subreddit, word, label, sort = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(desc(subreddit)) %>%
  group_by(subreddit) %>%
  slice(1:10)

FrequencySubreddit <- Top10 %>%
  plot_ly()
```

```
structure(list(subreddit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L), levels = c("addiction", 
"alcoholism", "anarchy", "CanadaPolitics", "centrist", "Conservative", 
"CryptoCurrency", "domesticviolence", "Eyebleach", "feedthebeast", 
"geopolitics", "Home", "LifeProTips", "lonely", "MadeMeSmile", 
"meirl", "mentalhealth", "neoliberal", "NoStupidQuestions", "offmychest", 
"pcmasterrace", "propaganda", "rape", "Republican", "schizophrenia", 
"science", "selfharm", "Shitstatistssay", "socialism", "techsupport", 
"Vent", "WatchPeopleDieInside", "YUROP"), class = "factor"), 
    word = c("addiction", "sober", "drugs", "stop", "clean", 
    "hard", "addict", "days", "recovery", "quit", "drinking", 
    "alcohol", "drink", "sober", "aa", "stop", "alcoholic", "days", 
    "quit", "luck", "capitalism", "anarchism", "property", "definition", 
    "anarchist", "anarchy", "government", "anarchists", "lol", 
    "society", "government", "canada", "party", "tax", "vote", 
    "change", "system", "liberals", "ndp", "issue", "trump", 
    "left", "party", "republicans", "democrats", "government", 
    "political", "biden", "vote", "election", "trump", "left", 
    "vote", "democrats", "government", "country", "conservative", 
    "biden", "shit", "party", "crypto", "btc", "market", "buy", 
    "bitcoin", "eth", "lol", "price", "moons", "reddit", "abuse", 
    "leave", "relationship", "abuser", "family", "hard", "abusive", 
    "situation", "love", "support", "dog", "cat", "cute", "love", 
    "dogs", "cats", "lol", "animals", "baby", "happy", "mod", 
    "mods", "pack", "game", "minecraft", "modpack", "server", 
    "world", "blocks", "version", "china", "chinese", "russia", 
    "war", "countries", "world", "power", "country", "india", 
    "government", "house", "water", "door", "wall", "paint", 
    "home", "wood", "tape", "fix", "clean", "job", "lpt", "pay", 
    "home", "water", "car", "shit", "house", "school", "makes", 
    "friends", "love", "talk", "hope", "happy", "lonely", "friend", 
    "hard", "women", "birthday", "love", "happy", "lol", "kids", 
    "guy", "hope", "nice", "kid", "shit", "beautiful", "lol", 
    "shit", "women", "love", "fuck", "guy", "friends", "pretty", 
    "house", "fucking", "mental", "therapy", "talk", "therapist", 
    "health", "depression", "hope", "anxiety", "hard", "feeling", 
    "pretty", "shit", "trump", "lol", "government", "war", "world", 
    "country", "literally", "vote", "question", "pretty", "world", 
    "reason", "makes", "live", "pay", "women", "water", "answer", 
    "love", "hope", "friends", "relationship", "happy", "talk", 
    "hard", "friend", "care", "family", "pc", "gpu", "games", 
    "cpu", "card", "game", "buy", "power", "ti", "ram", "propaganda", 
    "russia", "war", "lol", "russian", "media", "wing", "ukraine", 
    "country", "trump", "rape", "happened", "sexual", "talk", 
    "hope", "sex", "raped", "fault", "trauma", "consent", "trump", 
    "democrats", "vote", "left", "republicans", "party", "republican", 
    "country", "biden", "election", "schizophrenia", "symptoms", 
    "meds", "voices", "hope", "psychosis", "delusions", "hard", 
    "medication", "talk", "women", "study", "kids", "pretty", 
    "science", "covid", "world", "research", "makes", "health", 
    "cut", "harm", "hope", "sh", "scars", "talk", "clean", "stop", 
    "cutting", "hard", "government", "free", "property", "market", 
    "system", "pay", "private", "tax", "capitalism", "shit", 
    "socialism", "socialist", "capitalism", "class", "world", 
    "government", "party", "system", "capitalist", "left", "windows", 
    "drive", "issue", "pc", "computer", "power", "check", "usb", 
    "laptop", "cpu", "hope", "love", "friends", "talk", "shit", 
    "hard", "care", "women", "friend", "understand", "guy", "shit", 
    "lol", "fuck", "video", "fucking", "dude", "wrong", "pretty", 
    "literally", "eu", "germany", "russia", "europe", "country", 
    "uk", "war", "countries", "european", "german"), label = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("MentalHealth", 
    "Political", "Random"), class = "factor"), n = c(1330L, 708L, 
    706L, 612L, 602L, 554L, 542L, 538L, 502L, 494L, 3176L, 2403L, 
    2050L, 1481L, 1112L, 916L, 796L, 796L, 716L, 564L, 131L, 
    111L, 108L, 105L, 99L, 99L, 95L, 92L, 82L, 80L, 6497L, 5591L, 
    4097L, 3410L, 2839L, 2579L, 2526L, 2513L, 2464L, 2444L, 2353L, 
    1778L, 1651L, 1480L, 1382L, 1351L, 1306L, 1143L, 1099L, 1094L, 
    9412L, 8564L, 6930L, 5737L, 5478L, 5182L, 4816L, 4789L, 4781L, 
    4557L, 37790L, 17442L, 17339L, 15421L, 15397L, 13328L, 11266L, 
    9997L, 9057L, 8943L, 647L, 444L, 316L, 312L, 306L, 302L, 
    301L, 299L, 298L, 271L, 3930L, 3500L, 2160L, 2103L, 1801L, 
    1680L, 1162L, 1018L, 931L, 908L, 5288L, 4419L, 3125L, 1757L, 
    1584L, 1558L, 1526L, 1468L, 1438L, 1423L, 5171L, 2163L, 2008L, 
    1920L, 1819L, 1650L, 1469L, 1398L, 1257L, 1171L, 579L, 487L, 
    378L, 350L, 297L, 260L, 204L, 201L, 174L, 172L, 5785L, 4686L, 
    4601L, 4453L, 4352L, 4297L, 4046L, 4041L, 3631L, 3624L, 4047L, 
    2955L, 2677L, 2396L, 2364L, 1896L, 1849L, 1778L, 1636L, 1474L, 
    14586L, 10645L, 9343L, 7269L, 7246L, 6910L, 6737L, 6373L, 
    6009L, 5894L, 10566L, 9240L, 8970L, 7954L, 7801L, 6860L, 
    5720L, 5636L, 5597L, 5436L, 3632L, 3402L, 2944L, 2687L, 2645L, 
    2564L, 2536L, 2532L, 2272L, 2204L, 9228L, 8445L, 8245L, 8018L, 
    7737L, 7437L, 7187L, 7119L, 6971L, 6744L, 31799L, 20101L, 
    19067L, 18863L, 18524L, 18502L, 17496L, 16726L, 16549L, 16437L, 
    10765L, 8908L, 7383L, 6913L, 6515L, 6310L, 6080L, 5893L, 
    5799L, 5586L, 34405L, 29401L, 25535L, 25124L, 22366L, 19316L, 
    18495L, 17629L, 17564L, 17340L, 162L, 127L, 94L, 63L, 60L, 
    54L, 49L, 48L, 42L, 41L, 607L, 499L, 325L, 309L, 303L, 257L, 
    238L, 227L, 226L, 224L, 553L, 455L, 373L, 367L, 354L, 321L, 
    308L, 291L, 284L, 213L, 1796L, 1509L, 1373L, 1115L, 927L, 
    926L, 785L, 730L, 729L, 727L, 11067L, 10612L, 7666L, 5476L, 
    5427L, 5340L, 5171L, 5167L, 5101L, 5088L, 2098L, 1862L, 1685L, 
    1516L, 1369L, 1308L, 1247L, 1140L, 1103L, 1095L, 1683L, 805L, 
    614L, 566L, 565L, 563L, 524L, 482L, 443L, 434L, 2069L, 1846L, 
    1616L, 1217L, 1203L, 1039L, 1003L, 973L, 958L, 956L, 10469L, 
    7359L, 5776L, 5362L, 4843L, 4621L, 4365L, 4132L, 3953L, 3852L, 
    1601L, 1580L, 1567L, 1408L, 1278L, 1190L, 1096L, 1062L, 1008L, 
    974L, 4722L, 3860L, 3554L, 2820L, 2418L, 2415L, 2175L, 2104L, 
    2054L, 1672L, 1100L, 877L, 868L, 842L, 806L, 646L, 619L, 
    600L, 506L, 490L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -330L), groups = structure(list(
    subreddit = structure(1:33, levels = c("addiction", "alcoholism", 
    "anarchy", "CanadaPolitics", "centrist", "Conservative", 
    "CryptoCurrency", "domesticviolence", "Eyebleach", "feedthebeast", 
    "geopolitics", "Home", "LifeProTips", "lonely", "MadeMeSmile", 
    "meirl", "mentalhealth", "neoliberal", "NoStupidQuestions", 
    "offmychest", "pcmasterrace", "propaganda", "rape", "Republican", 
    "schizophrenia", "science", "selfharm", "Shitstatistssay", 
    "socialism", "techsupport", "Vent", "WatchPeopleDieInside", 
    "YUROP"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:10, 
        11:20, 21:30, 31:40, 41:50, 51:60, 61:70, 71:80, 81:90, 
        91:100, 101:110, 111:120, 121:130, 131:140, 141:150, 
        151:160, 161:170, 171:180, 181:190, 191:200, 201:210, 
        211:220, 221:230, 231:240, 241:250, 251:260, 261:270, 
        271:280, 281:290, 291:300, 301:310, 311:320, 321:330), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Instead of providing your dataframe in table form, can you provide it using `dput(tidysub_filter)`? `dput` makes your code easier to reproduce.

Comment: I will edit the post in a bit to reflect that. I might only be able to provide the head of the dataset since it's pretty extensive.